# Why did Sean dismiss the pact as fake news?

Tags: plot-explanation, bombshell

In this scene from *Bombshell* (2019), Geraldo reacts to the news about sexual harassment accusations against Fox News CEO Roger Ailes. Sean enters and asks about a reported pact among top Fox News talents to walk out if he is fired. Neil supports the pact, while Jeanine Pirro and Anchor #1 are unaware of it. Anchor #1 suggests Roger initiated the pact, but Sean dismisses it as fake news:

> Anchor: Roger placed it.
>
> Sean: **Fake news**.

Why did Sean dismiss the pact as fake news?

Comment: saying "fake news" doesn't mean "I think you're mistaken, I don't believe that's true
", it means "I'm going to say that's a lie because I don't want you to believe it"